# Linq - Join collection with child collection of other collection

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I have a collection of users, each with a child collection of memberships. And then I also have a club collection. The child collection of each user is populated with memberships containing a club ID only. What I want is for each membership to also contain the club entity matching the club ID.

My entities:

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
}
public class Membership
{
    public Guid ClubId { get; set; }
    public Club Club { get; set; }
}
public class Club
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Populated with data:

```cs
var club1Id = new Guid("FFEB77B9-1616-463B-B36E-F95F7E255FDE");
var club2Id = new Guid("7A6ECD38-5AEB-418B-9DD5-FBD777CE190C");

var users = new List<User>
{
    new User
    {
        Name = "Patrick Stewart",
        Memberships = new List<Membership>
        {
            new Membership { ClubId = club1Id },
            new Membership { ClubId = club2Id }
        }
    },
    new User
    {
        Name = "Brent Spiner",
        Memberships = new List<Membership>
        {
            new Membership { ClubId = club1Id }
        }
    },
    new User
    {
        Name = "Wesley Crusher",
        Memberships = null
    }
};

var clubs = new List<Club>
{
    new Club
    {
        Id = club1Id,
        Name = "Officers Club"
    },
    new Club
    {
        Id = club2Id,
        Name = "Captains Club"
    }
};
```

And then I need a LINQ query that adds the matched Club objects to the Membership objects.

So that when I print out users like this:

```cs
foreach (var user in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"User: {user.Name}");
    if (user.Memberships != null)
    {
        foreach (var membership in user.Memberships)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"  Membership: {membership.Club?.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

It will look like this:

```
User: Patrick Stewart
  Membership: Officers Club
  Membership: Captains Club
User: Brent Spiner
  Membership: Officers Club
User: Wesley Crusher
```

I want to do it in one go with a LINQ expression, so that I don't have to involve for-loops.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: It's Linq to Objects. I've updated with tag.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it with this LINQ expression:

```cs
users = users.Select(user => new { 
        user, 
        Memberships = user.Memberships?
        .GroupJoin(clubs, membership => membership.ClubId, club => club.Id, (membership, club) => new { membership, club})
        .SelectMany(mc => mc.club.DefaultIfEmpty(), (mc, club) =>
        {
            mc.membership.Club = club;
            return mc.membership;
        })
    })
    .Select(x =>
    {
        x.user.Memberships = x.Memberships;
        return x.user;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not intended to be used for modifying data, rather querying data and/or creating new data from data.

Instead, use a nested `foreach` loop.

First, create a `Dictionary` to make finding `Club` objects easier:

```
var clubDict = clubs.ToDictionary(c => c.Id);
```

Then, use the `clubDict` to modify each `Membership` to include the matching `Club` entity:

```
foreach (var user in users.Where(u => u.Memberships != null))
    foreach (var membership in user.Memberships)
        membership.Club = clubDict[membership.ClubId];
```

Comment: The reason why I stated that I didn't want to use for-loops is because in real life this is part of a more complex scenario, where there are a number of different collections I need to join with "user". I don't have detailed knowledge about the inner workings of LINQ, but I kind of assume it will do things more optimized than me doing a number of for-loops. I guess it's difficult to say for sure without implementing it both ways and then measure running time.

Comment: @maze_dk Correct, in general you should measure, however in the specific case of LINQ to Objects, the `for` loop will be faster than the `foreach` loop (in general, there are specific type optimizations in the compiler) and they will both be faster than LINQ. One reason is there is no lambda required to be called for the operations in each step. You don't use LINQ for performance, you use it for comprehension and database access, and I would argue comprehension is hurt by LINQ in this case. Also, lambda with side effects in LINQ is considered a bad practice.